# NSInvalidArgumentException with NSSet in Ordered CoreData Relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, swift, nsexception, nsorderedset

I have a CoreData project in which I have several objects witch several relationships.
One of them is an ordered To-Many relationship from an object **A** to many objects **B**.
I'm using the automatically configured obj-c classes which I use in my other Swift code with the help of a bridging header.

When I want to add objects **B** to a parent object **A**, my App crashes with:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSOrderedSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'
```

Which I believe is because of the following code:

```
objectA.addBObject(objectB)
```

It's a function in the obj-c class of object A and the NSOrderedSet it refers to is declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *B;   //The B objects
```

and the function:

```
- (void)addBObject:(B *)value;
```

How can I solve this error ? I've already read some threads but no one helped me.
Thank you !

Comment: can you show the code for the addBObject method?

Comment: This is a well-known bug in the generated accessor method for *ordered* relationships. The questions that I linked to has answers with possible workarounds.